# Can we change the value of a Kusto column for a record before ingesting it to the Kusto table?

Tags: database, bigdata, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have created an Azure Data Explorer(ADX) cluster and  a table(call it ABC). The data is ingested into the Kusto table via the built in pipeline in ADX - (ingests data from azure blob via event grid). I have also created a JSON ingestion mapping using which the data is ingested. I have a field in the incoming data which is in its abbreviated format. Is there a way (maybe a Kusto function or some property in Kusto ingestion mapping) which allow me to refer - maybe another table in Kusto with the corresponding abbreviation and full form, and ingest the full word instead of abbreviated word to the table? The incoming data is fast, so I guess heavy computation won't be feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy). The source table can have zero retention policy and serve as a staging table only.